# The [velocity] tag gets misused by [meteor-velocity] users - rename?

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

Although [[velocity]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/velocity) and [[meteor-velocity]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/meteor-velocity) are two different tags with correct descriptions I have seen several[1] questions misusing the `[velocity]` tag when actually referring to `[meteor-velocity]`, due to being unaware that there is that *other* velocity.

Maybe the (current) `[velocity]` could be renamed to `[apache-velocity]` to make the distinction more obvious? (Other renaming suggestions welcome.)

[1] Non representative: I counted 3 out of the 15 most recent referring to Meteor.

Comment: I call and raise you with [velocity.js] which is also can be mistaken with [velocity], I created [apache-velocity] tag and think that some/most of the [velocity] questions need to be migrated