# Velocity tag wrong synonym to appfabric-cache

Tags: support, tag-synonym-process

The [velocity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/velocity) tag is actually apache-velocity because its name is mistaken by the dictionary velocity and also by JavaScript's [velocity.js].

I created [apache-velocity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-velocity) and wanted to connect them, but I found that I can't because velocity is already synonym to [appfabric-cache](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/appfabric-cache/info)
(appfabric-cache × 158    velocity × 1871).

appfabric-cache:

> Microsoft Windows Server AppFabric, formerly codenamed “Velocity,” provides a distributed cache that you can integrate into both Web and
>   desktop applications.

velocity tag:

> Apache Velocity is a Java-based template engine. It can be used to
>   dynamically generate web pages, email messages, source code, or any
>   other text file.

Obviously the synonym isn't correct and have 0 votes, but I can't downvote the appfabric-cache synonym, and the appfabric-cache tag have only one question in 2017, and I'm not sure anyone can/will vote on this synonym, is there a time limit for synonym acceptance?

Can velocity to appfabric-cache synonym be removed? And after it should I make apache-velocity as the velocity synonym, or can they both merge?

- There's [an open question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291714/the-velocity-tag-gets-misused-by-meteor-velocity-users-rename) about confusion also between [velocity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/velocity) and [meteor-velocity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/meteor-velocity) which is unanswered.

Another suggestion [velocity-tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/velocity-tools) has only 3 questions with also [velocity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/velocity) so it can be `burninated`.

Comment: Looks like this synonym was removed

Comment: The wrong synonym still exists https://stackoverflow.com/tags/appfabric-cache/synonyms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The synonym you're talking about](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/appfabric-cache/synonyms) *does not exist*.

It has merely been *proposed*. That's why it currently has a score of 0. If you have the required score in the tag, you can vote on the synonym, either up or down. A vote up indicates that you agree with the synonym and think it should take effect. A vote down indicates that you think the synonym is inappropriate. At a score of 4, the synonym is approved automatically. At a score of −2, the synonym will be rejected. It says all of this on the linked page:

> Users with more than 2500 reputation and a total answer score of 5 or more on the tag, can suggest tag synonyms. Users with a total answer score (total upvotes minus total downvotes) of 5 or more on the tag, can vote for tag synonyms. Suggestions will be automatically approved when they reach a score of 4, and automatically deleted when they reach a score of -2.

If there's no one who meets the requirements to vote on the synonym, then it'll never get approved (unless a moderator approves it, and we wouldn't do that without some prior discussion). It isn't hurting anything for the synonym to sit there proposed. It has absolutely no effect on the site.

Comment: But I can't create tag velocity synonym for apache-velocity because of the tag proposal I get :Synonym velocity already proposed on the tag appfabric-cache

Comment: I could see an argument for removing that synonym suggestion, but it seems wildly inappropriate to make [velocity] a synonym of [apache-velocity] when it already refers to many different things, including Velocity.js, Windows Server AppFabric, and speed with direction.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, can appfabric-cache suggested synonym be removed?