# Tag synonym removal/burnination

Tags: support, tags, tag-synonym-process

There is a lot of [tag removal/burnination](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356963/tag-removals-must-be-discussed-and-documented-on-meta) process and requests, But I didn't find any information about **tag synonym** removal/ burnination.

I have a question also about [remove tag synonym](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355563/velocity-tag-wrong-synonym-to-appfabric-cache) to appfabric-cache but didn't get any answer yet,

If tag synonym created with 0 votes and (almost) no active user available for voting will the tag by removed automatically by a process or by submitting special removal request or it can't be remove in any other way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Active tag synonyms can be removed by a moderator, if the community decides that the synonym is inappropriate (or circumstances change). The direction of a synonym's mapping can also be reversed, such that the synonym becomes the "master" tag, and the former "master" tag becomes the synonym.

What you found and described in [the other question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355563/velocity-tag-wrong-synonym-to-appfabric-cache) is a *proposed* tag synonym, not an active one. It has a score of 0, so it hasn't taken effect. If it had taken effect, it would be listed higher up on the page, as one of the actual synonyms, and it wouldn't have any vote arrows. A randomly-chosen example of a tag that has actual, active synonyms is the [dos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dos) tag, as you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/dos/synonyms). Note that there are no pending suggested synonyms there.

No, there is no automated process that removes pending suggested synonyms. They have to be either approved or disapproved by eligible community members via votes. At least part of the reason they aren't automatically removed for lack of interest is because (A) there are very few people who actually know about this feature, and (B) in smaller tags where synonyms are less likely to have already been created, there are a vanishingly small number of people who are actually eligible to cast votes on synonyms. "Expiring" them would do more harm than good.

Yes, a moderator could also remove a suggested synonym, but I don't see what the point would be in doing so. If you want to argue for that, a Meta question would be the appropriate way to do it.

Comment: What's the best way to propose removal of an active tag synonym?