# How to promote tag synonym proposal

Tags: support, tag-synonym-process

I added the [vtl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vtl) tag synonym to [apache-velocity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-velocity).

When I add a suggested tag synonym (I think it's my first), how can I (or the community) promote such a synonym to users?

For example, when I suggest a tag synonym, how will users in that tag be informed of such a synonym? Mostly users don't enter tag information, especially for a tag they frequently used and especially not clicking on [synonyms](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/apache-velocity/synonyms).

Is my tag synonym proposal only available for users searching the [tags synonyms](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms) queue?

How can I broaden exposure for my proposal (except asking on meta of course)?

Comment: meta is a great place to discuss and promote them. can you be specific for your case?

Comment: I added [tag:vtl] synonym to [tag:apache-velocity]. https://stackoverflow.com/tags/apache-velocity/synonyms

Comment: Strange how [tag:velocity] and [tag:apache-velocity] aren't synonyms. I don't have experience in either Java or velocity but they seem like the same thing.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355563/velocity-tag-wrong-synonym-to-appfabric-cache

Comment: I have exactly the same question about synonyms that I'd suggested. So far they got 0 exposure and attention. Should I ask a meta question as well?

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/204244/improving-tag-synonyms

Comment: 1. Meta post with pun 2. ??? 3. Synonym!