# How to write tag excerpt/info which have more than 1 meaning

Tags: support, tags

About writing tag excerpt/info, for example for [autolink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/autolink)

I found it confusing to handle such tags with more than 1 meaning,

It can have [google analytics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/linker) context

> autoLink method

Or [android context](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html)

> android:autoLink   Controls whether links such as urls and email addresses are automatically found and converted to clickable links.

I can refer you to [velocity hell tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355563/velocity-tag-wrong-synonym-to-appfabric-cache) that tag usage will become very confusing later.

What can/should we do in such scenarios? write all possible contexts? ask for change of tag name? ignore such tags?

Comment: If a tag's meaninf is open to interpretation like that, it's a unclear tag, and may even need to be burninated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot write an excerpt for a tag with different meanings. These are *ambiguous tags*.
You can check if they can be disambiguated into multiple tags with clear meaning. The questions will then be retagged based on the separated tags. Check some requests in [tag-disambiguation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tag-disambiguation). You can then write an excerpt for the disambiguated tags.

If the tag is very generic and meets the burnination criteria, you can create a burninate request [burninate-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/burninate-request). Criteria can be seen [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-tag-removal-burnination).